# How to convert LPTSTR to QString

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

Hi can anyone help me to convert LPTSTR to QString

Comment: http://www.qtforum.org/article/944/how-to-get-windows-login-name.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will see in [the docs](http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/qstring.html) that Qstring provides static function to convert from both ascii and Unicode strings:

- QString fromAscii ( const char *
  ascii, int len = -1 )
- QString fromLatin1 ( const char *
  chars, int len = -1 )
- QString fromUtf8 ( const char * utf8,
  int len = -1 )
- QString fromLocal8Bit ( const char *
  local8Bit, int len = -1 )
- QString fromUcs2 ( const unsigned
  short * str )

Check whether you are using ascii or unicode and pick your poison.

Answer (score 7):

[QString::fromWCharArray](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qstring.html#fromWCharArray) is what worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

To convert QString to LPTSTR or LPCTSTR:

```
QString src;   
LPTSTR dest=(LPTSTR)src.utf16();
```

to convert from LPTSTR or LPCTSTR to QString :

```
src=QString::fromUtf16(dest);
```

Answer (score 1):

**The solution expects that your LPTSTR array is null-terminated.**

```cpp
STRRET str; // it had been filled by a winapi function

// str.pOleStr is LPWSTR, i.e. wchar_t* field of the union STRRET
// LPWSTR is the same as LPTSTR (see further)

QString result{QString::fromWCharArray(str.pOleStr)};
```

As shown below, `STRRET` is a union, one of representations of which (named `pOleStr`) has type `wchar_t*`.

As far as I understand, when one gets this `STRRET` filled by a Winapi function (like e.g. `IShellFolder::GetDisplayNameOf()`), it's a normal null-terminated wide string. So it can be supplied to [QString::fromWCharArray(const wchar_t *string)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromWCharArray). The function will preserve the input  `wchar_t`-array as it is and will just create a new copy inside a new `QString`. So overall, I think the method in my answer is quite safe as far as you know that your `const wchar_t *` is ended with a `\0`-wide-character.

```cpp
// shtypes.h
typedef struct _STRRET
    {
    UINT uType;
    /* [switch_is][switch_type] */ union 
        {
        /* [case()][string] */ LPWSTR pOleStr;
        /* [case()] */ UINT uOffset;
        /* [case()] */ char cStr[ 260 ];
        }   DUMMYUNIONNAME;
    }   STRRET;
```

```
// winnt.h
typedef _Null_terminated_ WCHAR *NWPSTR, *LPWSTR, *PWSTR;
typedef LPWSTR PTSTR, LPTSTR;
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing! If you find time please edit an explanation into the answer as it's recommended to [explain entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421) on StackOverflow.

Comment: @SvenViking I did my best.

Answer (score 0):

Use **QString::fromUcs2** to convert strings.

Answer (score 0):

This is woking fine

QString str("ddddd");
LPCTSTR lstr = (LPCTSTR)str.data();